How do Lithium ion batteries work?
I saw a diagram and the li-ion circuit had a power source, if someone does explain the working maybe explain with like an actual picture of what that source exactly does.

What diagram? show us. Also, the question in the title does not match the one in the body.

The question in the body is just telling any1 who is going to answer the question in the title what to specify because I'm pretty sure people r gonna leave that part out of the explanation. The diagram in question is just any basic diagram of a li-ion battery, point is there is a power source in it. I had a feeling people were just gonna say this is a power source, it powers the thing, provides energy and stuff. What I'm asking is to emphasise on it. Which type of energy, how does it provide it, etc.

Which type of energy ... electro-chemical ... research how to make battery from lemon

So now you have an answer with a picture of a Li ion battery that does not say anything about a power source.  So can you please follow Solar Mike's suggestion and show us the diagram you're referring to, so we can understand your question?

I think an internet search would have sufficed to answer this.
Here's one of many articles explaining how lithium ion batteries are constructed.
https://batteryguy.com/kb/knowledge-base/what-are-lithium-ion-batteries/

As with most batteries, a chemical reaction produces the electric current.
